# HBD195 NPN Silicon Transistor replacement

Tags: transistors

[image]

Please help me to find the suitable replacement for this transistor

Thanks

[image]

Please find the image of PCB kit, I am using 6V battery to work with HBD195, again thanks everybody for the quick reply

Answer (score 2):

Even though product recommendations are off topic, I will still provide an answer to it.

If you want to find a suitable replacement component, the best thing to do is go to a site such as [digikey](https://www.digikey.co.uk/), [farnell](http://uk.farnell.com/), [RS](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/) and such and use the tools available on the websites.

It doesn't take long to go to the 'Transistors' page and put in the parameters you need. It is so easy to customise your search and find the components you want. When you have a few you think may work, compare datasheets. If it does everything you want it to do, you have a replacement.

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

A suitable replacement for use in what circuit?

Choosing a replacement is mostly about understanding what the device is being asked to deliver in the target circuit. This overrides making comparisons between data sheet A and data sheet B. After all, is anyone really to know whther the package (TO-126) is important or whether a TO-220 would be fine.

What about voltage rating - you might be using it on a low voltage supply so finding a device that met the 50 volts collector-base voltage could be a waste of time.

Is it really important that the reverse base-emitter voltage rating is 8 volts or will something that is only rated at 6 volts be enough? How can anyone tell this from the data sheet.

Finding a replacement is the same as choosing a part that is suitable for the original design - you determine functionality and performance expectations for the target circuit and choose a device based on this.